# Is IE 11 the latest and available for Windows 8 Pro x64?

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I'm running Windows 8 Pro, x64, fully patched. It has Internet Explorer 10.0.9200.17116 installed. I checked Windows update and there are no updates available.

I had a popup spring from somewhere, and it stated to download the latest version of Internet Explorer. I *think* it may have come from the check box below (or then again, it may have been a phishing attempt):

[image: IE10 Popup]

I found it kind of odd, so I went to Microsoft's download for *Internet Explorer 11 x64*. Here's what Microsoft's download page told me:

[image: IE11 Message]

There's a ***Next*** button available (*not* shown above), so I followed it. The next page presents me with:

[image: IE11 Options]

The two pages confuse me. Is IE 11 the latest and available for x64 or not? If I attempt the download and install, will Microsoft corrupt this system so I have to reinstall?

Comment: IE11 cannot be installed on Windows 8 only Windows 7 and Windows 8.1; if you want IE11 upgrade to 8.1; it's not possible to upgrade to IE11 with Windows 8.0

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound. Microsoft should have stated it as succinctly as you. Better, Microsoft should not have given the impression the download is available on the second screen. It would have saved me and other who read this question a lot of time.

Comment: @Ramhound this is an answer, not a comment. So post it as answer.

Comment: When I clicked on your link, AVG 2015 claimed that it was a virus- "Virus found JS/FakeCodec". And that last picture's content in your question (as is the weblink) is VERY suspicious. So it IS a phishing attempt. Doesn't "Superior HD Video Streaming and Hardware Acceleration+Download Any Movies, Shows or Video Clips" sound a bit too good to be true? ;)

Comment: The second screenshot you provided is crystal clear. The URL your asking about isn't even a Microsoft website, you should remove it, so not to promote malware websites

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here the answer from *Ramhound*:

> IE11 cannot be installed on Windows 8 only Windows 7 and Windows 8.1;
>   **if you want IE11 upgrade to 8.1**; it's not possible to upgrade to IE11
>   with Windows 8.0

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer 11 is included in the Windows 8.1 or Windows RT 8.1 update

From:
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-8/browse-web-internet-explorer-tutorial

Answer (score 1):

For things like internet Explorer, unless you are an early adopter, Windows Update will take care of that. There are no popups to install browser updates for any current browser - these are all scams. Even if there were popups that are not scams, there are always ways to install updates through the official sources, just the way you tried to do.

The screenshots explain what is going on - You can download Internet Explorer 11, but it won't run on your system. This is an option provided for people who want to download it from one machine and then install it on another machine, as explained in the first screenshot. The installer will not corrupt the system, it will simply refuse to install on a system that is not supported.

Now, here's the tricky part: Windows Update should handle Windows Updates, but in the case of the update from Windows 8 to Windows 8.1, it doesn't. That's the update for Windows 8 which includes Internet Explorer 11. This update you have to install through the Windows Store (go to the start screen, type "Store", click the green "store" icon). You'll find the update there and then you can download and install it. For detailed instructions see: **http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/update-from-windows-8-tutorial**

Be aware that the update from Windows 8 to Windows 8.1 is not available if you are running Windows 8 64 bit on a very old 64 bit CPU which is missing some required instructions from its instruction set.