# IE 10 crashes on 'File Upload' when using EMET

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer, crash, emet

This problem has been occurring for quite some time now for me (at least two to three weeks).

Whenever I try to upload an image, IE crashes. It crashes because [EMET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2458544) stops an illegal operation. The message from EMET is:

> EMET detected **Caller** mitigation and will close the application: IEXPLORE.EXE

Here's from *Event Viewer* and the *Application* log:

```
EMET detected Caller mitigation and will close the application: IEXPLORE.EXE

Caller check failed:
  Application   : C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE
  User Name     : ...
  Session ID    : 1
  PID       : 0x94C (2380)
  TID       : 0xEC8 (3784)
  API Name  : ntdll.NtCreateFile
  ReturnAddress     : 0x0917B24A
  CalledAddress     : 0x77BBE060
  TargetAddress     : 0x0917A820
  StackPtr  : 0x026CF55C
```

I have plug-ins from the usual suspects disabled, like the Java plug-in and the junk from Adobe. The only plug-in running is Microsoft's Silverlight.

The system is Windows 8 (x64), fully patched. IE is 10.0.9200.17116, and EMET is 5.0.5324.31804.

What can I do to upload an image with Internet Explorer when using EMET.

Comment: First step;  Verify the problem exists with 8.1 and IE11.  You offer no details on the upload method.

Comment: @Ramhound - Sorry, I don't have an 8.1 system. And Microsoft [will not allow me to install IE 11](http://superuser.com/q/829281/173513).

Comment: **8.1 is a free upgrade**

Comment: How exactly are you trying to upload this image, and to where? Is it only with a specific site, or ANY site that you try to upload to?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 - it happens when I click "upload File" (or whatever the site uses). The crash occurs when the the "Choose a File to Upload" dialog box is shown. I have confirmed it with Super User (that's why there's no image here), Stack Overflow, Web Apps SE, and PostImage.

Comment: @ Ramhound - Windows 8.1 is not an option for me at the moment. There are three reasons. First, this machine is part of a multi-boot laptop using GPTs. I can't risk Windows breaking things. Second, Microsoft f--k'ed up the User Interface even further. My laptop is *not* a phone, so I only use the traditional desktop (and not the phone manager desktop with touch tiles). I don't want their crippled attempt at a Start Button further f--k'ing up my UI. Third, I have not reviewed the License Agreements ensure they are acceptable (I'm still using iOS 6 because I don't agree with Apple's iCloud ToS).