# Windows 8.1 upgrade blew out other OSes on GPT disks?

Tags: windows-8, boot, multi-boot, gpt, efi

I was multibooting an EFI laptop. The laptop was using GPTs, was using SecureBoot, and it had Windows 8.0, Ubuntu, Fedora and Debian on it.

I updated the laptop to Windows 8.1 through the free App Store update because I could not get [security updates and bug fixes for Windows 8.0 and IE 10](https://superuser.com/q/829281/173513).

Now, I can no longer access any of the other operating systems. It appears Windows 8.1 blew out the other GPTs during its upgrade, and not just its own GPT. I don't see any other disks under Disk Management; and the EFI's boot screen (not the Windows Boot Menu) does not list any other operating systems.

I have two questions:

- What happened to the other GPTs and Operating Systems?
- Is there anyway to undo what this plague known as Windows 8.x has done?

Answer (score 0):

Can you make clear whether SecureBoot

1. was
2. is

enabled?

And obviously, if it was not enabled and if it now is enabled, then reversing it to [**not** using SecureBoot](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn481258.aspx) would help.

Comment: This is probably better suited as a comment since it does not provide an Answer (sometimes the community downvotes them, so its a friendly fair warning). To get back to your question: YES, SecureBoot was being used.

Comment: True enough, but yesterday I did not have enough reputation (on Superuser.com) to be able to comment on the original issue. Thanks to you for your friendly warning.